# go JSON nightmare - Is there a simple [POSH] ConvertFrom-Json equivalent?

Tags: json, go

In powershell, if I make a REST call and receive any kind of json response, I can easily `$json | ConvertFrom-Json` into a proper object so I can make modifications, render specific values, whatever.

It seems like in Go I have to either define a `struct`, or "dynamically" convert using a `map[string]interface{}`.

The issue with a `struct` is that I am writing a rest handler for a platform that, depending on the endpoint, serves wildly different JSON responses, like most REST APIs. I don't want to define a `struct` for all of the dozens of possible responses.

The problem with `map[string]interface{}` is that it pollutes the data by generating a string with a bunch of ridiculous 'map' prefixes and unwanted [brackets].

```
ala: [map[current_user_role:admin id:1]]
```

Is there a way to convert a JSON response like:

```
{
   "current_user_role": "admin",
   "id": 1
}
```

To return a basic:

```
current_user_role: admin
id: 1
```

... WITHOUT defining a `struct`?

Comment: So you just want to list the fields of the JSON that you get in your request?

Comment: I'd prefer to know if I can convert it to a slice(?) so I can work with it as an object or array, but honestly I'd settle for just understanding how to straight convert the key / value pairs cleanly.

Comment: The brackets and map shown in the question are an artifact of printing a value with the `fmt` package.  Are you asking how to print values in a simpler format?

Comment: Oh really? I wasn't even aware fmt would add superfluous data. Any insight on how to return a json response as a slice or even just the key/values without the extra bits would be helpful. 

In powershell it's really just a matter of ```Invoke-RestMethod | ConvertFrom-Json```. Hell in python I could do what I need with just a json.loads(var). I'm basically looking for the Go equivalent of those 2 operations. In neither Python nor powershell do I have to first define a struct, all of the values are inherited from the JSON body itself.

Comment: How do you imagine a representing a JSON object as a slice?

Comment: that's a big part of my lack of understanding. In powershell and python I can take any json statement and with a single operation convert it to an array or list. In Go, Slices seem to be more akin to PSObjects than Go Arrays, so I was using slices as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach of using a map is right if you don't wish to specify the structure of the data you're receiving. You don't like how it is output from `fmt.Println`, but I suspect you're confusing the output format with the data representation. Printing them out in the format you find acceptable takes a couple of lines of code, and is not as convenient as in python or powershell, which you may find annoying.

Here's a working example [(playground link)](https://play.golang.org/p/DTAsWDrxRBC):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

var data = []byte(`{
   "current_user_role": "admin",
   "id": 1
}`)

func main() {
    var a map[string]interface{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &a); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for k, v := range a {
        fmt.Printf("%s: %v\n", k, v)
    }
}
```

Comment: Paul, you are 100% correct in that I am conflating how fmt was presenting the data with how the data was presenting. If I, say, print in python or write-out in powershell, it prints the data largely as-is so my assumption here was that fmt.println was doing something similar.